# Hide the snippet in the markers so users can't see the postId

Tags: java, android

The issue is that for my markers on the map I have the title which is fine, and then for the `snippet()` I inserted the `postId` so that later I can use that `postId` for the `OnInfoWindowClickListener` to search for it in the database and if it matches it takes the user to the `PostDetailFragment` which has all the post's data...

Obviously I don't want the user to see the `postId` when they click on the marker the info Window comes up, but at that moment the snippet should hide, so I need to replace it, or make it invisible, or GONE...

Also, to identify the markers I tried using `setTag()` and `getTag()`, but it didn't work.

Suggestions? I need to hide or make invisible the snippet in each tag so the users don't see the `postid`, BUT I need the `postId` to run the query in the database.

Maybe there's a better way to do this?

**MapFragment**

```
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                // MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(post.getText_event()).snippet(post.getText_location() + " \u25CF " + post.getTime());
                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(post.getText_event()).snippet(post.getPostid());
                                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
                                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                                // Info Window

                                mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(marker -> {
                                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                                            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                                                Post pos = snap.getValue(Post.class);
                                                if (pos != null) {
                                                    if (marker.getSnippet().equals(pos.getPostid())) {
                                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                                        editor.putString("postid", marker.getSnippet());
                                                        editor.apply();
                                                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PostDetailFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the default marker has some of those limitations.

What you should do is create a class called CustomMarker that implements ClusterItem then you can use that as the Marker.

ClusterItem is simply a Marker.

```
public class Marker implements ClusterItem {

    private final LatLng positiond;
    private final String markerId;
    private final String title;
    private final String tag;



    private final Post post;


    private final String snippet;

    public Marker(LatLng positiond, String markerId, String title, String snippet, Post post,String tag) {
        this.positiond = positiond;
        this.markerId = markerId;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.post=post;
        this.tag=tag;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return positiond;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    public String getMarkerId() {
        return markerId;
    }
    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }
    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }
    
}
```

The above is a Marker. Then you can just pass the Post into the Marker like so above.

When you create the marker/clusterItem you can pass the MarkerID as the PostId then when you click it. you can get the markerID then perform any of the logic you want.

Comment: What's up buddy! Thanks for responding... I've been doing some research and would it be possible to use the setTag(); and getTag(); methods? I've tried, but I couldn't figure it out. You think it could work, or is this the better way to do it in your opinion?

Comment: Instead of default marker you just need to create an object of type CustomMarker then pass any data you have defined inside the class definition

Comment: But should I be saving that data separately from all my other data in the database using HashMap? Like title, position, etc... Or does ClusterItem just allow me to retrieve that data for each marker somehow?

Comment: It largely depend on your logic...You can persist the data if you want.

Comment: Okay I'll try it out I suppose and see if it works... If not I'm hitting you up!

Comment: It should work. Just think of the Marker class above as a replacement of the default Marker. But with added fields.

Comment: Okay you let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218145/discussion-between-david-innocent-and-jmb).

Comment: It's not letting me get through to the chat … Delete it and re-post it please!

Comment: no the default Marker can not accept those fields. That is why we have ClusterItem...the maps guys at google provided that so that you can easily extend the capabilities of the Marker to suit your needs.

Comment: https://mindorks.com/android/store/Maps/sharewire/google-maps-clustering should give you a way forward.

Comment: Hey man, I figured out a much easier way to do it. I spent way too long trying to figure out how to make a custom marker, so I just added a ```GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter``` and added the TextViews that way. Works, and was less of a hassle... Thanks for the help though. I appreciate it!